# Redirect all image URL's to a different domain using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a live & a staging site (WordPress), for testing purposes the db will be migrated from live to staging, however I would like all image file references to remain pointing to the live site.
During the migration process all URL's are rewritten in the db.
So in essence what I want is a way I can catch all .jpg, .gif, .png & potentially .pdf, .doc URL's & redirect them to the live site.
So http://staging.example.com/image.jpg would be rewritten & actually point to http://example.com/image.jpg
Hopefully you see what I mean, I'm trying to get around migrating the media library from one site to the other, given that the staging site is only a temporary testing ground for some updates.
Any tips greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

To redirect image files from olddomain to the newdomain ,you can use

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png|gif|pdf|jpg|doc)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: That looks simple & straightforward, & thanks for your reply - but I'm not having any luck as yet. Any possible issues around the way Apache is set up on my hosting environment?